# Is there a method to do search query in firebase (admin) while using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I like to search the database and see if an app is already been submitted. I tried:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();
ref.query('name=' + formData.name, function(searchResult) {
  if (searchResult.length == 0) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    response.write(userInfo);
    response.end();
  } else {
    response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    response.write('App existed.');
    response.end();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
ref.orderByChild("name")
    .equalTo(formData.name)
    .once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
        });
    });
```

ref.query('name=' + formData.name, function(searchResult) {

I highly recommend that you spend some time in the Firebase documentation, which explains this and many more concepts. A few hours there, will save you many hours (and questions) down the line.

Particularly relevant to this question are:

- the section on [database queries with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries)
- the section on [database queries with the Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) (which works the same, but docs explain it differently)

Comment: thanks, since the "name" isn't the direct child of ref (it would be the grandchildren), would it still work?

Comment: The query I shared is the equivalent of `'name=' + formData.name`. If you already have a data structure, **edit** your question to include a minimal snippet of that JSON (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: actually this seems to work, I just tried. if I don't want to use forEach, instead I just need to check this first one, like `snapshot[0].val().name`, can I do that? why does it throw `undefined` error?

Comment: A snapshot is not an array. You will have to loop over it as the code in my answer does. If you only want the first result, you can `break` from the loop.